# Change default port for Hyperledger Fabric playground

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to run a local instance of Hyperledger Fabric playground, and I am currently trying to start my server.  However, the default port is :8080, and that port is always consumed by an internal app.  Is there a way to change it to something different?  For reference, I am using Docker, and running `docker run --name composer-playground --publish 9999:8080 --detach hyperledger/composer-playground` doesn't update my listening port.

Comment: I was able to run the command and access the playground on http://localhost:9999. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @zstate huh, it's running...I didn't check, because when I run `composer-playground`, I get an error print that basically says :8080 is already in use.